# Can't update or query embedded sub-documents using MongoDB? Now what?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I took the NoSQL plunge against all my RDBMS prejudices from my past.  But I trusted.  Now I find myself 3 months into a project and the exact reasons we adhered to RDMS principles seem to be biting me in the butt.  I think I just discovered here on stackoverflow that I can't work with twice embedded arrays.  I followed the noSQL, embedded document approach like a good kool-aid drinker and feel like I've been betrayed.  Before I swear off noSQL and go back and refactor my entire code-base to adhere to new 'normalized' model I'd like to here from some no-sql champions.

Here is my model using one big document with embedded docs and the works:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
User = mongoose.model('User');

var Entry = new Schema({
   text: String,
   ups: Number,
   downs: Number,
   rankScore: Number,
   posted: { 
     type: Date, 
     default: Date.now 
   },
   postedBy: {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: 'User'
   }
});    

var boardSchema = new Schema({
  theme: String,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  entered: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  entries: [Entry],
  participants: [{
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    topTen: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Entry'} ]
  }]
});
mongoose.model('Board', boardSchema);
```

Basically, I want to query the document by Board._id, then where participants.user == req.user.id, I'd like to add to the topTen[] array.  Note participants[] is an array within the document and topTen is an array within participants[].  I've found other similar questions but I was pointed to a Jira item which doesn't look like it will be implemented to allow the use of $ positional operation in multiple embedded arrays.  Is there no way to do this now?  Or if anyone has a suggestion of how to model my document so that I don't have to go full re-write with a new normalized reference model...please help!

Here are some of my query attempts from what I could find online.  Nothing worked for me.

Board.update({_id: ObjectId('56910eed15c4d50e0998a2c9'), 'participants.user._id': ObjectId('56437f6a142974240273d862')}, {$set:{'participants.0.topTen.$.entry': ObjectId('5692eafc64601ceb0b64269b') }}

I read you should avoid such 'nested' designs but with the embedded model its hard not to.  Basically this statement says to me "don't embed" go "ref".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The fact that how you get to use a NoSQL datastore has nothing to do with your problem and even made your question hard to read.

Comment: I am actually taking a step back and reading the O'Reilly book on MongoDB.  I am doing a few things wrong I can tell already.